# Android equivalent for C#'s Application.DoEvents();

Tags: android

Is there a function in Android that will update or keep the UI responsive?

I know that you are meant to do all tasks in a helper thread, but that is not what my question is.

So you could run something like this and the application would not close?

```
while(true)
{
  UpdateUI;
  counter++;
```

}

Please not the example is just an example in terms of the question. That is not the code I am trying to run.

I know that this is a odd question, Don't hate on me. Just answer No if its not possible.

Comment: It will be much easier to help if you will provide details or the code you're trying to run

Comment: On a side node: `Application.DoEvents()` per see is a bad technique and very discouraged even in C#. One is to use threads and Tasks in C#. Same applies for Java and every other language where you have an UI

Answer (score 1):

The UI (main) thread is doing event processing all the time. The UI is kept responsive by making sure that all event handling code executes fast and does not block the thread for a long time.